# Как во время компиляции сконвертить int к string в golang?

Tags: golang

Имеется константа, которая является частью другой константы. Они разных типов:

```go
import "strconv"

const (
  NUMBER = 123
  STRING = "NUMBER = " strconv.Itoa(NUMBER)
)
```

Этот код не заработает, так как `strconv.Itoa()` не `const`, как можно на моменте компиляции сделать из `int(123)` `string("123")`? Чтобы все таки в константу `STRING` записалось значание.

Comment: Никак, в нём нет препроцессорных директив, или макросов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как тебе уже указали, простых способов нет.

Но есть непростые :)

Если это прямо вот такая проблема, что обязательно требует решения (могу себе только представить только некую библиотеку, в которой много взаимозависимых констант, потому что в своём приложении нужно просто объявить `var` и не париться), то можно написать генератор, который будет генерировать файл с константами и вызывать его перед билдом

```
go generate
go build
go test
```

Ссылки по теме

- https://go.dev/blog/generate
- https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2021/a-comprehensive-guide-to-go-generate/

Comment: воу, генератор исполняемых файлов это конечно ближе к костылю, но спасибо за идею